# I need to import text file but not as a string?

Tags: vb.net

Code :

```
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:***\Documents\Eureka\Users\favourites\favourites_container.txt"

    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

    If FILE_NAME.ToString.ToCharArray.Contains(WebBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath) Then
        favouritebtn.Hide()
        not_favouritebtn.Show()
    Else
        favouritebtn.Hide()
        not_favouritebtn.Show()
    End If
```

Error: Text is not a member of String

How do i get that to work? Basically if the Web Browser's URL is in the text file, then favoruitebtn shows but if isnt in the textfile not_Favouritebtn shows? Sorry, i am applying all i know but i just get the error. Thanks

Comment: string.Contains doesn't do what you think

Comment: Thanks for that, any idea what would? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `String.Contains` incorrectly, and need to read the file line by line:

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\Eureka\Users\favourites\favourites_container.txt"    
Dim reader as StreamReader= My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(FILE_NAME)
Dim a as String
Do
    a = reader.ReadLine
    If a.Contains(WebBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath) Then
        favouritebtn.Hide()
        not_favouritebtn.Show()
    Else
        favouritebtn.Hide()
        not_favouritebtn.Show()
    End If
Loop Until a Is Nothing 
reader.Close()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but im still getting the Object set to no object instance (null error)? Please help haha, im so lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read the content of the file using the StreamReader or just calling File.ReadAllText, then checking the resulting string your Url

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "......"
Dim fileContent = File.ReadAllText(FILE_NAME) 
If fileContent.Contains(WebBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath) Then
    favouritebtn.Hide()
    not_favouritebtn.Show()
Else
    favouritebtn.Hide()
    not_favouritebtn.Show()
End If
```

Be warned however that if the file is really big, reading all the content in memory is not a good approach

Comment: Thanks, and nope short :)